# Screen record in IOS

Tags: swift, flutter, screen, record, flutter-method-channel

I am using flutter to create an app that will record the screen in the background.

For android, I'm using the ed_screen_recorder package from pub.dev but in IOS this package doesn't work when the app is in background.
I think this functionality can be reached in swift and call the method via MethodChannel in flutter but I only found the ReplayKit framework whose function is to record the screen inside the app.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Highly doubt that is possible in iOS, I have never tried I just doubt it is possible.